# Replace thermostat with rasberry pi and Solid state relay

Tags: solid-state-relay

I want to replace my thermostat with raspberry pi board. I have already connected solid state relay to rasberry pi and it works just fine. The only part left to do is to connect solid state relay to the thermostat. I have an idea how to do that but before actually connecting anything I want to ask your advice if I am doing it right. 
My solid state relay looks like this

[image: solid state relay]
<sub>(source: [asia.ru](http://www.asia.ru/images/target/photo/50641195/Solid_State_Relay.jpg))</sub>

And the diagram on the thermostat looks like this

[image: diagram]

I have 4 cables

```
Blue - N
Red - L
Call - yellow
and ground yellow/red
```

So I think I should connect Red(L - Red) to SSR contact 1(ac in) and CALL (yellow) to the SSR contact 2 (Load). Is that the right way to do ?

P.S. Its in UK so voltage is 220V therefore I want to be extremely careful

Comment: If you were being really careful, you'd replace your thermostat with a thermostat!

Comment: Does anyone know what "CALL" means in this context? Is it "Call for heating" (or cooling for an air-con)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **connect Red (L - Red) to SSR contact 1 (ac in) and CALL (yellow) to the SSR contact 2 (Load)?**

Yes, that seems correct. You should make safe the neutral wire and prevent it from any possibility of coming into contact with any other wiring, metal parts or the outside.

> **It's in the UK, so voltage is 220V**

The EU standard is 230 V ± 10% but in the UK you'll typically measure 240 V which is within this range and is what substations for UK domestic supplies were previously standardised on. Other EU countries had previously standardised on 220 V, not the UK.

> **I want to be extremely careful**

That means going to the consumer-unit (fuse-box) and switching off the circuit marked "boiler" or "heating", then checking your thermostat connections with a safe voltage tester (preferably non-contact) before rewiring them. keep the Pi well away from 240 V wires, ideally in a separate, well-insulated box.